# JsonSerializer does not contain definition for Parse

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

On the tutorial that I am following, they have this line of code

```
var keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer.Parse<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonBytes);
```

but my visual studio is giving me an error of

> JsonSerializer does not contain a definition for Parse

and this is my import

```
using System.Text.Json;
```

Comment: You sure you've imported the correct JsonSerializer class from the right package? Doesn't look to be json.net

Comment: Where is the tutorial? The error means you need to reference some assembly; This may have been stated in the tutorial.

Comment: @CodingYoshi It's this one https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-configuring-role-based-authorization-with-client-side-blazor/

Comment: The entire code for that tutorial is on [GitHub](https://github.com/chrissainty/RoleBasedAuthWithBlazor) so download the code from there and it should work.

Comment: Actually I did download it, but the thing is why is it that in my code this is not recognized?

Comment: I got it. the method parse has been changed to deserialize

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Parse` method has been replaced with `Deserialize` method.

Proof:

On [the tutorial](https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-configuring-role-based-authorization-with-client-side-blazor/):

```
private IEnumerable<Claim> ParseClaimsFromJwt(string jwt)
{
    ...
    var keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer.Parse<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonBytes);
```

But on [GitHub](https://github.com/chrissainty/RoleBasedAuthWithBlazor/blob/56a4ffe92784c5f479d780f87aed9b74ea7bc918/src/ClientSideBlazor.Client/ApiAuthenticationStateProvider.cs)

```
private IEnumerable<Claim> ParseClaimsFromJwt(string jwt)
{
     ...
     var keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonBytes);
```